# What is the correct argument divider character for Google Sheet functions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on some Google Sheet and tried to use the following function as documented, though I received a parsing error in the formular. I double checked the given URL, the range format, nothing worked, especially e.g. not referencing one concrete cell like `"A24"` only. So I googled around about that error message and found a lot of things to check which weren't the problem in my case, like wrong quote characters, additional parenthesis. Though, at some point I found an example using exactly the same function I was using and that example used `;` instead of `,` as the divider for arguments. Gave that a try and, surprise, things worked instantly as expected and documented, e.g. I received the documented permission check dialog. Though, [the docs clearly use a `,` everywhere](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?sjid=12807173387158774130-EU) and I found a lot of other code examples using `,` instead of `;`. So I additionally tested other function calls with arguments as well and whenever I use `,`, I receive the formular parsing error again. Changing to `;` resolves that error for each used function.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("[...]", "25!A24:P24")
```

vs.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("[...]"; "25!A24:P24")
```

While my Google Sheet is created in a German language context, browser, account language etc., there's a setting to use fixed function names always and that setting doesn't seem to make a difference. Additionally, `,` vs. `;` should trigger some encoding or localization issue.

**How can that be?**

Comment: [this should be helpful](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/)

Comment: That's it, thanks! Please create an answer with the link and some most important quotes from the source so that I can give you the credits.

Answer (score 2):

**----------------Edit----------------**

I just noticed after posting this answer that @rockinfreakshow actually had this answered on a comment, I will leave this answer for visibility but if he wants to create his own please note that he was the first one to answer this question and I will remove mine if the information is repetitive.

**----------------Original answer----------------**

This is 100% because of the language you have chosen, the same happens in Italian and Spanish.

To fix this you should [change the locale settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en#zippy=%2Cchange-locale-and-time-zone), although that makes it sound like you will be changing the language, in reality you are changing the default behavior of characters, it is described as changing the "default currency, date, and number formatting" but in reality it also changes the argument divider of formulas.

Also the "Always use English function names" checkbox only works to show the functions in English so that functions such as NOW() are written with their English names instead of their localization such as ADESSO() (Italian)  or AHORA() (Spanish).

Changing the locale should allow you to use commas if you'd prefer but feel free to let me know if you happen to have any further questions.